# Template class that can take either a size_t parameter or pointer-to-member

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Is there a way I can specialize a template class based on whether one of the template arguments is a `size_t` or a pointer-to-data-member?

For instance:

```
template<typename container_t, size_t offset>
struct SomeClass
{
    // Some implementation
    static void foo() {}
};

template<typename container_t, int container_t::*member>
struct SomeClass
{
    // Another implementation
    static void foo() {}
};

SomeClass<MyClass, 123>::foo();
SomeClass<MyClass, &MyClass::someMember>::foo();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17, yes with `auto`,

```
template<typename C, auto>
struct SomeClass;

template<typename C, size_t N>
struct SomeClass<C, N>
{
    // Some implementation
    static void foo() {}
};

template<typename C, int C::*member>
struct SomeClass<C, member>
{
    // Another implementation
    static void foo() {}
};
```

Before, you have to add extra parameter.

```
template<typename C, typename T, T value>
struct SomeClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind passing the type as an additional argument, you can get away with this in any C++ version.

```
template <typename container_t, typename T, T offset>
struct SomeClass;

template <typename container_t, size_t offset>
struct SomeClass<container_t, size_t, offset> {

};

template <typename container_t, typename T, T container_t::*member>
struct SomeClass<container_t, T container_t::*, member> {

};
```